# Why is GitHub displaying a non existent image?

Tags: github, markdown

I have a mark down document in GitHub with some images that are hosted on my  webserver. I've redone some of the images but the changes aren't reflecting on the page. I have sequence diagram that points to: http://www.massstreet.net/documentation-images/etl-framework/DimensionLoadSequenceDiagram.png

That's the correct image. However the image on GitHub, from my perspective, is still the old image and stubbornly refuses to go away.

https://github.com/MassStreetAnalytics/etl-framework/blob/master/Documentation/Chapter%2001%20-%20ETL%20Developers%20Guide.md

I've cleared my cache. I've switched to different computers. I cleared the cache on those machines. I've committed changes to the md file. What is going on here?

Comment: When I got to your github .md page, it takes me to a content-provided/cached version of your image, not the massstret.net one.  Perhaps that is part of the issue?

Comment: Those images looks quite similar to me, though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is cases by **server side** image caching by GitHub.

Add `?` to the end of image URL - for example: `![ETL Diagram](http://www.massstreet.net/documentation-images/etl-framework/ETLDiagram.png?)`

It will **evict** the cache. You may try to remove `?` once the problem is fixed.

Comment: That got it. When i tried to removed the ?, it just went back to the cached version. Funny though. I changed the first two diagrams too and they changed just fine without the ?.